# Openlayers Labels: Prevent displaying of .123 as 0.123

Tags: javascript, openlayers

So i am getting some Text from a database and put them as Points on a Vector Layer and put the Text into a Label. Problem is that some of the Text thats starts with a '.' following some numbers like are treated like numbers and receive a '0' at the beginning.

For Example: ".341" is shown as "0.341". Internal the Text comes from the Database as ".341", pre Feature insert it is ".341" and after Feature insert it is still ".341". Also with typeof i always get "string".

In following Code you can see where the label is set:

```
var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
        fillColor: "#ffcc66",
        strokeColor: "#ff9933",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        label: "${text}",
        fontColor: "#333333",
        fontFamily: "sans-serif",
        fontWeight: "bold"
    }
```

If anyone got a clue how to prevent it to be written with '0', would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i haven't found a way to do it with any options, i went ahead and found the code thats responsible. Copy pasted into my .js to overwrite it and outcommented the line responsible:

```
OpenLayers.Style.createLiteral = function(value, context, feature, property) {
    if (typeof value == "string" && value.indexOf("${") != -1) {
    value = OpenLayers.String.format(value, context, [feature, property]);
    //value = (isNaN(value) || !value) ? value : parseFloat(value);
    }
    return value;
};
```